# Add different instantiations of a template class in the same container and call a template class method

Tags: c++, templates, containers

Suppose I have these classes:

```
class A
{
   // virtual methods
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A
{
    void ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB(...){...};
}
```

I would like to add a subset of B classes into a container and from there, call `ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB`.

For example, given:

```
B<instanciation1> south_park;
B<instanciatoin2> family_guy;
```

suppose I want to put `B<instanciation1>` and `B<instanciation2>` in the same container  (for example a vector): I cannot declare a `std::vector<B>` because `B` is not a real class, only `B<instanciation1>` and `B<instanciation2>` are.

Then I thought to define a vector using a (shared) pointer to the base class. However, doing so gives error when calling `ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB` because the method is not defined in the base class (and no, I can't modify the base class adding the method there).

Is there a way create a container with two different instances of a template classes and call a method that all of the instantiated classes have but not the parent class of the template class?

Comment: Suppose you could do `std::vector<B> vec;`, do you expect `vec[0].ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB()` to work? Well it can't, what if there is specialization of `B` which doesn't have that method? All template instantiations are completely unrelated.

Comment: @quimby I know that and I explicitely said it in my question, I am asking if there is a workaround, and in case it exists how does it work.

Comment: @Francesco you cannot modify `A`. Can you create a `class myB` which inherits from `A`, add `ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB` to `myB` and then have your `B<T>` inherit from `myB`? Then you can just add pointers to `myB` in your container

Comment: and I wanted to demonstrate that any workaround won't be able to store any `B`. Can you modify at least `B` if not `A`?

Comment: Forget for the moment that `B` is a template. Write two ordinary derived classes, `C` and `D`, and figure out how to get that to work. Then look at making a template.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two ways around this:

1. You might define an intermediate class, `AWithSpecificMethod`:

```
class AWithSpecificMethod {
protected:
    virtual ANewMethodSpecificOfClassB() const = 0;
};
```

Then have `B<>` descend either from `A` or from `AWithSpecificMethod`. You can do that using `std::conditional<>`, `std::is_same<>` et. al.

However, this way of solving it, at some point, creates several interfaces and immediate classes which are not true abstractions, just a notation of existence of method. Also, it's virtual => likely very slow.

2. You might store them in an `std::variant<B<T1>, B<T2>, ...>` and reconsider even if `A` is necessary as an interface class. This works if you know the possible types T1, T2, ... that you intend to work with (practically almost always). You can visit a `variant` using `std::visit`, which you usually pass a lambda and the variant:

```
std::variant<B<int>, B<char>> var;
std::visit([&](auto const& actual) {
    // here actual is the concrete type
    // either B<int> const& or B<char>&
}, var);
```